# WSE 3.0 on framework 3.5 under Program Files(X86)

Tags: frameworks, web-services-enhancements

I am deploying a web application to a windows server 2003 machine.
The application uses WSE 3.0, and targets framework 3.5.
WSE is installed on the server under C:\Program Files(X86)\Microsoft WSE\v3.0.
WSE is installed in the GAC on the server also.

when I run the application I get the following error:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Has anybody had this problem?

Thanks,
Carter

Answer (score 1):

Put it into the Bin folder of your website. If its there and is still having a problem, use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find any related files that may be missing.